# Remove $array[] where key value pair x = x

Tags: php, arrays

The output of the below makes `$new_array` contain multiple arrays with an `id`, `date` and `type`.

```
$new_array = array();

foreach($things as $thing )(

    $new_array[] = array(
        'id' => $thing['id'],
        'date' => '2017-01-01',
        'type' => $thing['type']
    );

)
```

If I `print_r( $new_array )` this gets me all the arrays inside, but then I want to modify this array and remove all the arrays inside which don't have a specific `type`.

To do this I assume I need to unset any `$new_array[]` arrays where the key value pair `type =>` equals `x`.

How do I acheive this? I have read into unsetting key value pairs but this doesn't help me with it being multiple arrays.

Comment: [`$new_array = array_filter($new_array, function($n){ return $n['type'] !== 'x'; });`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)?

Comment: Just check if `$thing['type']` is equal to x and if yes don't even add the subArray to the array. If you want to filter the array afterwards you probably want to use `array_filter()` or do it with a simple foreach loop and `unset()`.

Comment: What is $things ?

Comment: It's a big array of things, I want to make a smaller array combining some of the things from it with some new stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should check first before adding the array:

```
foreach($things as $thing ){
  if(!empty($thing['type']) && $thing['type'] == 'my type'){
    $data[] = [
      'id' => $thing['id'],
      'date' => '2017-01-01',
      'type' => $thing['type']
    ];
  }
}

print_r($data);
```